# How to map Stored Procedure params when using Stored Procedure for CRUD?

Tags: entity-framework

Suppose I have a table like:
Person(ID, Name, DOB, ...)
I use EF to create model with VS2010. Then I want to use SP for CRUD. say my SP for insert like:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Person_Add] 
(@DOB datetime, @NAME varchar(10)= null,@PersonType as int)
AS
    Begin
    ...
    End
```

Param @PersonType is someting I want to use in SP for some extra business logic, but it is not part of the table and model.

Then I use design surface for SP mapping. When map above SP for Insert function, edmx will ask me to map the param @PersonType, but there is no way to map it.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps: 
1. Import the stored procedure into the model. 
Edit the model in XML Editor: 
2. Remove the redundant parameter. 
3. Add [CommandText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmfunction.commandtextattribute.aspx) to this procedure in which you can execute the procedure itself.